# Cannot work with integers in Verilog

Tags: types, integer, verilog

I've been trying to figure out why I'm getting "invalid module instantiation" when using:

```
integer counter = 0; 
counter = 1; // <-- getting the error here
```

I'm getting the same error when trying to use reg[7:0] instead of integer.

Does anybody have any idea why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The assignment without a context is pretty useless and doesn't mean anything, thus the error. Assignment would have been valid within a block with a sensitivity list, or as part of continuous assignment, or inside a simulation block like "initial".